# Where in this string of characters is the Kernel Version number?

Tags: kernel, versions

```
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-25-generic    5.11.0-25.27~20.04.1    amd64    Signed kernel image generic
```

I am trying to delete old kernels. The highest number is the most recent kernel but I don't know what the version number is. Where is it is along that string of characters?

I ran `uname -r` and got:

```
5.11.0-41-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 10 10:20:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So I'm pretty sure that it is the most recent, but I would like to
know what I'm looking at.

Comment: You ran `uname -rv` not `uname -r`.  `uname -r` will only return the release number like `5.11.0-41-generic` and when you run `uname -r` it returns the running kernel and not the newest kernel..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running kernel version `5.11.0-25-generic`:

[image: Here You Go]

The current version for stock 20.04 – as of this answer – is `5.11.0-40-generic`. You may want to update your OS in the near future to ensure you have the latest security updates at the very least

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove old kernels, there is an easier method ...

`sudo apt autoremove --purge`

or

`sudo apt autopurge`

In addition to old kernels, it will also remove any packages that may have been installed but are no longer needed.